# Is there a cross browser way to prevent cut, copy and paste on a website in plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I found an answer, but it was for JQuery. Here is the link:

http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/12/disable-cut-copy-and-paste-function-for.html

: I want something in plain Javascript which work on chrome, latest firefox, safari, and IE 8 and 9.

### Update

Due to all the negative comments saying that this is a bad idea for an internet site I can only say "I agree". Please note that this is for an "intranet" application where cut, copy, and paste need to be overidden as the default browser behaviour for cut copy and paste needs to be customized to handle embedded tags in a rich text area

Comment: No. And don't try to break my user experience.

Comment: And if the person disables JavaScript on the page? View page source and copy the text, use Firebug. You *CAN NOT* prevent it. If the page is displayed in the browser, the content is saved to the user's computer.

Comment: If you don't want people to copy your data, don't put it on the internet.

Comment: @incognito - This is for an intranet application where copying and pasting text can really mess up a rich text area for the end user, because of embedded tags. Please not that the question was not "Is it a good idea to disable cut, copy , and paste?" :)

Comment: @deceze - Yes, I agree. It is not an internet application

Comment: @epascarello - The purpose is not to prevent copying. In fact we need to provide our own specialised copy ans paste buttons, so it is to "enable" copying and pasting

Comment: Your updated question makes more sense. That's why you should always provide as much information as possible with a question. :)

Comment: @deceze - Yes, I haven't used stackoverflow much recently, so I'm just relearning some of the basics again :)

Comment: @Zubair Give more details in the future and people will not assume what you are doing. Do you know how many times people ask to prevent coping on their site?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

of course it is not appropriate to do stuff like this, but that was not @Zubairs question, so i think voting down is not correct here, as he made his point clear.

now to the question: if jQuery can do it, native javascript can do it of course too.

you must prevent the cut, copy and paste events:

```
document.body.oncopy = function() { return false; }
document.body.oncut = function() { return false; }
document.body.onpaste = function() { return false; }
```

this prevents the right-click-context-menu, this is not needed if you use the 3 other event-handlers but just to let you know ;-)

```
document.body.oncontextmenu = function() { return false; }
```

IMPORTANT: the body must be loaded (of course), document.body because IE needs it (document.oncopy will only work in chrome/firefox/safari)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try this. And thanks for supporting and upvoting the question. I'm going to start posting more often on stack overflow if I can get this level of excitement generated every day! :)

Answer (score 3):

a good way

```
var D=document.getElementById('b4');

if(D.addEventListener){
D.addEventListener('paste',function(e){false;e.preventDefault();},false);}
else{
D.attachEvent('onpaste',function(){return false;});}
```

**warning** : code must be under html target/s , 
just before the close body tag for example

Answer (score 2):

Edit: adding this to a body tag seems to work on all of my test browsers including the Opera, Chrome, Seamonkey (so I assume Firefox) and IE9

`<body oncopy='return false' oncut='return false' onpaste='return false'>`

you can put them in other tags if you want to allow some functions in some places and not in others

Comment: Thanks for trying and not flaming me :) but that doesn't work in IE9 :(

Answer (score 1):

You can catch a `[Ctrl]+[C]` keypress:

```
addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    evt = (e) ? e : window.event; // Some cross-browser compatibility.
    if(evt.ctrlKey && evt.which == 67){ // [x] == 88; [c] == 67; [v] == 86;
        console.log("Ctrl+C pressed!");
        evt.preventDefault(); // Cancel the copy-ing function for the client.
        // Manual Copy / Paste / Cut code here.
    }
});​
```

**[Working snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/6drrX/)**

Comment: Please note that the question was not "Is it a good idea to disable cut, copy , and paste?". Please read the comments below the question

Comment: The first line of my answer _exactly_ answers your question: "There is _no_ cross browser way to prevent cut, copy and paste on a website in plain Javascript." Nothing that's reliable, at least.

Comment: If it is not possible then how does this site do it? http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/12/disable-cut-copy-and-paste-function-for.html

Comment: You are asking for plain JavaScript, that site is using jQuery, also, that script is easily broken. (Meaning unreliable)
I understand it's not the answer you want, but that's not a reason to downvote. There is simply no reliable, foolproof, cross-browser way to prevent copy-paste.

Comment: Editing the answer after a comment on the question, a moment please.

Comment: Could you show me how demo for that site http://jsbin.com/uyuzo breaks? I tried ctrl-v and paste from the menu and it still doesn't paste into the text box, so it appears to work correctly

Comment: It uses jQuery and event listeners not supported by some browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Could you let me know which browsers do not support event listeners, as we will only go ahead with this is if it is a cross browser solution? Thanks

Comment: Like I said, there is no reliable cross-browser solution available that doesn't use jQuery. Even with jQuery, the behaviour will be hit-and-miss at best.

Comment: So are you saying that JQuery can do things that can't be done with normal Javascript?

Comment: Also, the first iPhone did not have cut, copy and paste, and customers "did" say it was awesome!

Comment: Yes and no. jQuery -is- javascript, but the library has a lot of compatibility features built in.
I edited a piece of code to catch `[Ctrl]+[C]`. This works in Chrome, if you run it in a `"onload"`. But the device never had the functionality in the first place. You are _taking away_ a functionality, instead of _not adding_ it, yet.

Comment: I +1 your answer now for the great debate :)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.
I also added some more code, as far as I know, that snippet is as compatible as you can get it, using native JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```
oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false"
```

This code will be prevent cut, copy and paste of a website.

[Working Snippet](http://faruk247.blogspot.com/2017/07/how-to-disable-cut-copy-and-paste.html)